# Philosophy of virtualenv

Tags: pip, debian-buster, virtualenv

Can somebody explain the philosophy of virtualenv?

I fully understand how it works - if I use scripts by hand. I've to enter to some folder, run virtualenv and do what I want in secure environment. The philosophy of chroot.

BUT

I'm not using python scripts by hand. Everything is automatic.

1. I run some_script.py by cron.d - should I run some extra script, which will activate some environment, run some script, than deactivate? (will this script run?:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /myenvs/
    virtualenv app1
    source app1/bin/activate
    my_script.py
    deactivate
   ```
2. Where should venvs reside (in Debian, which has very strict policy for folders)
   And the apps are installed inside the venv or outside?

I wonder if venv is some kind of profile:

E.g. I install some app `apt install some_app` and it installs inside /var/lib/some_app

And now I can:

1. use it normal (without venv) `run_my_app`
2. run it in virtual app `virtualenv app1; source app1/bin/activate; run_my_app`
3. run it in different virtual app `virtualenv app2; source app2/bin/activate; run_my_app` e.g with different version of jinja

or I think wrong

3. How to use it with nginx/apache - now nging/apache run wsgi.application from some folder. But how to run it inside venv?

many questions - no google answers. Every answers explains it: it is very easy to use. enter to venv and you are secure... But I don't use my apps in that way.

Why am I asking? Because pip warns me to install packages inside venv. I would do it with pleasure. By noone explains how to.

Comment: Perhaps "philosophy" is not the best term for this question? We don't really do philosophy questions here because Superuser is not the developer and only the developer can tell us the philosophy behind a given product or solution.

Comment: @music2myear change Philosophy into concept. I tried to ask very precise question - how to use virtualenv in production.